# Loading log4j file with java standalone app is not loading log4j.properties

Tags: java, java-8, log4j, java-11

I have a public static void main standalone app and i am trying to load a log4j file so that i can write a particular logging pattern and and also write few rollling appenders.

I have following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But my log4j.properties  file is getting ignored. it is under java resources.

```
status=info
name=PropertiesConfig
filters=threshold
filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level=info
appenders=console
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=][%-5p|%c{1}|%M|%L|%replace{%m}{\r?\n}{}%n
#Logtoconsole
logger.app.name=PropertiesConfig
logger.app.level=info
logger.app.additivity=false
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref=STDOUT
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
```

I also tried loading it using Properties

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(Environment.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

What am i missing , please feel free to suggest a better approach.

Comment: The default configuration files for Log4j2 are named `log4j2.<extension>`, so you should name the file `log4j2.properties`.

Comment: thanks Piotr. i had tried that .  still not able to load the log4j2.properties.

Comment: i fugured out the root cause, in my project there is another dependency which has log4j2.xml. thats is overriding my log4j2.properties. how can i exclude it ?

Comment: overriding log4j2.xml solved my problem .